# TestFlight issue when removing then adding testers

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Using `iTuneConnect` and `TestFlight`, and for a given app I defined my '**app internal testers**' team.
All worked great for the last 6 weeks: I publish a new build for the app and everyone get notified and able to install and test the new app.

This morning, I wanted to publish a `TestFlight` version only for myself (to make sure the build is not broken). What I did:

- I removed temporarily all app testers, except myself, from the App
  internal test team (not from the global users list).
- I published the app and could install it without problem.
- I re-added the testers to the 'app internal testers' team.
  After that, i published twice new builds but no one except myself was receiving any notification or able to see the new build on `TestFlight`.

Any help on how to fix the issue above is appreciated

UPDATE1: One tester reported she is receiving 'The invitation has been revoked or invalid. Please request a new invite from the developer'

UPDATE2: After trying few times (more than once), to delete the testers and then re-add them again - All this using 'Admin' account (not 'Application Manager' account)- finally things started to work again for the testers. Strange. I personally have no explanation and will do my best NOT to delete any tester from an app.

Comment: Delete other testers once again. Logout for itunesconnect and then login back. Try to add testers back.

Comment: Check the mail from testflight and tap open in testflight button from there.